# CORS-issue - "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, cors

So I've been trying to pass data from my front-end to my back-end (however, I'm not very experienced within this area). The data comes through, however, if I try to insert the data into my MySQL-DB through PDO the browser gives me the following error:

> Failed to load http://localhost:8888/post_recipe.php: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

**JS**

```js
postToAPI = () => {
  fetch(`http://localhost:8888/post_recipe.php`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    },
    mode: 'cors',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      title: this.state.title,
      description: this.state.description,
      userID: this.props.userInfo.response.id,
      name: this.props.userInfo.response.name,
      stepByStep: (this.state.stepByStep),
      recipeIngredients: (this.state.recipeIngredients),
      profileImg: this.props.userInfo.response.picture.data.url
    })
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((fetch) => {
        console.log(fetch)
      });
  }
```

**PHP**

```js
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');

$post = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$array = json_decode(json_encode($post), True);

$pdo = new PDO(
  "mysql:host=localhost:8889;dbname=veganify;charset=utf8",
  "root",
  "root"
);

$statement = $pdo->prepare(
    "INSERT INTO posts (title, description, userID, name, stepByStep, recipeIngredients, profileImg)
    VALUES (:title, :description, :userID, :name, :stepByStep, :recipeIngredients, :profileImg)"
    );
    $statement->execute(array(
    ":title"     => $array["title"],
    ":description"     => $array["description"],
    ":userID"    => $array["userID"],
    ":name"        => $array["name"],
    ":stepByStep"    => $array["stepByStep"],
    ":recipeIngredients"        => $array["recipeIngredients"],
    ":profileImg"       => $array["profileImg"]
    ));
}

echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

So if I delete the MySQL-insertion, the data comes back to the front-end. I have been stuck here for a while now searching various forums for a solution. The error message says that the header is not present, however it is there, as you can see.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: with PHP https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Server-Side_Access_Control

Comment: Did you try to search for the error message (or parts of it) here on SO or with any search provider out there? You're absolutely not the first to encounter that problem.

Comment: _Side note:_ You should probably set the Content-Type to `application/json` instead of `text/html` since you're returning json and not html.

Answer (score 1):

Good afternoon, this is because of the apache blocking requests from different sources ie if your backend is at *http://yourdomain.com/client* and your font-end is at *localhost:3001* will cause a because they are of different (host) origins.

To solve:

Use the .htaccess file in your api / backend folder, for example, in my application my index.php is not in localhost / my-api / public directory then my .htaccess file in this directory directory localhost / my-api / public

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*" (allow access from any origin)
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "http://motech-ui.example" (allow access from only "http://motech-ui.example" origin)
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "http://motech-ui.example | http://other.domain" (allow access from two mentioned origins)
</IfModule>
```

Or config in apache.conf

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*" (allow access from any origin)
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "http://motech-ui.example" (allow access from only "http://motech-ui.example" origin)
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "http://motech-ui.example | http://other.domain" (allow access from two mentioned origins)
```

Comment: The server doesn't block the request, that's the job of the browser (check the response in the developer tools and you will see the content). The server only grants the browser the permission to access the content of the response (via `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`) if the origin of the request is different.

Answer (score 0):

CORS in Javascript and PHP works like.

1. **OPTIONS** method request will be triggered from browser side.
2. Server side (PHP) should accept the **OPTIONS** request, by responding **'OK'**.
3. Now a proper POST request will be triggered from browser side, which will go to your functionality location where your PHP code will gets executed.

   if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "OPTIONS") {
      //location where you can handle your request and respond ok
      echo 'OK';
   }

Answer (score 0):

If you can not control the sever side,  you can work around like me on

Client side only.

If you can control server side, you can use server side solution. I am not discus it here.

Only on client side, work around is

use dataType: 'jsonp',

```
   async function get_ajax_data(){

       var _reprojected_lat_lng = await $.ajax({

                                type: 'GET',

                                dataType: 'jsonp',

                                data: {},

                                url: _reprojection_url,

                                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                                    console.log(jqXHR)

                                },

                                success: function (data) {

                                    console.log(data);



                                    // note: data is already json type, you just specify dataType: jsonp

                                    return data;

                                }

                            });





 } // function
```